# primecoin? Node.JS vs Haskell applicability

Tags: algorithm, node.js, haskell, cryptography, payment

I was reading about [primecoin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primecoin) when it linked me to [Cunningham chains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cunningham_chain). Now that I know what a cunningham chain is, and I couldn't find an implementation in a good language, I need to implement it. Should I use Node.JS for it? I was thinking of using Haskell, but then I'd have to think to much. I think Node.JS will work better since it has better numerical support, and I can make a Node.JS website that uses socket.io to offload my prime computation to the background of clients using my website (essentially pay2view).

---

For example: One reason I thought haskell is suited for this is because you can make a lazy function that will stream out the values of each chain. Also runs on bare metal with no browser, but im not sure that's much of an advantage.

Comment: what is better numerical support in your opinion?

Comment: @Arjan: arithmetic operators work on all values. in haskell, it would get a type error. why waste my time writing `(read "42" :: Integer) + (1::Integer)` when I could write just `"42"+1`. (im sure there might be actual pros for Haskell though, so I made this question)

Comment: interesting question. personally, i rather use botnet in C, but I hear LUA is pretty good for this types of work cus flame implemented in it. see: http://www.foxnews.com/tech/2012/05/30/powerful-flame-cyberweapon-tied-to-powerfully-angry-birds/ LUA also have expressive power of node.js. has similar framework to node.js, luvit: http://luvit.io/

Comment: How should this be answered? Haskell has pretty much everything Node.js has and can even compile to javascript if you want the same language on your client, it's a matter of personal preference.

Comment: @jozefg what's your point? all turing complete languages can be compiled to each other. in practice there's huge performance loss and more bugs. Node.JS is right at the metal. Dude Bro luvit seems interesting i'll have to check it out...

Comment: @BROEST My point is that this is just opinions, bad for SO. For example, I was about to site your example of why JS is better for math as a reason of why haskell was better. Entirely opinions

Comment: It's like asking "Which language is better for Project Euler, Haskell or Javascript with Node".

Comment: @jozefg: so you're saying implementing on breadboard is the same as in haskell and node.js?

Comment: @megazord Don't be ridiculous, everyone has a language they like better and between JS and Haskell, you can spend all day arguing about which is better. I don't know how an answer to this question can be anything but "I like this better, so use this". Feel free to prove me wrong, but they're both expressive high level languages. Yes you can claim objectively that JS is better than assembler, but to me, Haskell > JS and to others JS > Haskell and I don't see any reason to flame war over something so trivial, just write it in some language :)

Comment: guys. question is simple. which of the 2 languages would better fit this task and why?

Comment: I agree with @megazord. If no language is better than the other, then why have multiple languages? To waste people's time?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Computing Cunningham chains effectively requires Bignums.

Node.js uses V8 which can efficiently represent 31-bit signed integers.  That isn't nearly big enough for Cunningham chains.

Haskell has architecture native integers and supports efficient Bignum calculation through GMP.

V8 does not yet have efficient Bignum support.

You are likely to get better performance from a Haskell implementation, particularly if you avoid using Strings entirely.

Comment: oh. Node.JS has no built in integer so it's bad for implementing primecoin. Makes sense. seems like I'm going with haskell.

Comment: Cool stuff. Hit us up in the Haskell Community either here, IRC (#haskell), or the mailing lists. http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Mailing_lists